# How to switch between jquery event methods?

Tags: jquery

Inside my plugin I have a method that runs click event and loads ajax

```
loadAjax: function () {


    self = this;
    $('.loadmore').click(function (event) {

           // load ajax and do some stuff
    });
}
```

I would like to make a switch to

```
$( window ).scroll(function(event) {

       // load ajax and do some stuff
});
```

but without rewriting the ajax lines again. 
The plugin also has an option for the loadaction which I can switch from click to scroll.

Is this at all possible without duplicating the ajax code?

Thank you!

Comment: it's possible in several different ways, all using functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try call different methods of object (main idea):

```
var customCall = {
  click: function(){
    $('.loadmore').click(function (event) {

       // load ajax and do some stuff
    });
  },
  scroll: function(){
    $( window ).scroll(function(event) {

     // load ajax and do some stuff
    });
  }
}, choice;

choice = 'click'; // loadAjax call click function

loadAjax: function () {
  self = this;
  customCall[choice]();
}

...

choice = 'scroll'; // loadAjax call scroll function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $(window).scroll() event to trigger the $('.loadmore').click() event.

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
    $('.loadmore').trigger('click');
});
```

Though you'll want to be careful with how often this event will be triggered. Maybe use a timeout, or determine how far the window should be scrolled instead of triggering on every scroll event.

Comment: I do not want to combine them , needs to be either or .